# Taking the address of a variable within a loop in C

Tags: c

Is this valid or does it have undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int *a = NULL;
 for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
   int b = 6;
   a = &b; 
 }

 printf("%d\n", *a);
 return 0;
}
```

Isn't it possible for `b` to be removed from the stack once it's out of the loop (and hence out of scope)?

Comment: Even `printf("%p\n", (void *) a);` is UB.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that will be undefined behavior. If you want to capture the value of `b` outside the for-loop, you can do `*a = b` inside the for-loop, but `a` will have to point to somewhere non-null prior in order for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behavior.

The variable `b` has *automatic storage duration*: its storage is deallocated at the end of the block it is declared in, that is the `}` of the `for` loop.

Then `a` becomes a *danging pointer*. Applying the dereference expression `*a` is undefined behavior in this case.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access

Answer (score -1):

Yes. That is undefined behavior once you get out of the loop.
`a` is pointing to an address that has gone out of scope and so is not usable.